# SQL Server : Replication Error - the row was not found at the Subscriber when applying the replicated command

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I got the following error in Activity Monitor,

> The row was not found at the Subscriber when applying the replicated command. (Source: SQL Server, Error number: 20598)

After some research, I found out the error occurs because it's trying to delete records which are not exists in the subscriber(Also are not exists in publisher)

```
{CALL [dbo].[sp_MSdel_testtable] (241)}
```

I can manually insert something to the record and the replication will move on. The problem I have right now is I don't how many bad records are there. Is there any fast way to do this? I already spends hours and inserted about 20 records.

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to re-initialize the subscription?

Comment: IDK, I havn't tried yet. It helps?

Comment: Yes, if you open the replication monitor in SSMS, and find the publication, you can right click it, and then select re-initialize.  If asked, generate new snapshot.  This will take a new image of your production data, and send it to the subscriber.  The log reader agent will pick up from that point.  If the tables are extremely large -- you may encounter delays while the snapshot is copied to the subscriber.

Comment: Also, once you have the subscriber fixed, you may consider restricting update/insert/delete to the replicated db so this mistake doesn't re-occur.

Comment: "You must run the Snapshot Agent to generate the snapshot". Where is Snapshot agent?

Comment: If you are in the replication monitor, click on the subscription on the left pane, and you'll find the snapshot agent under the "Agents" tab on the right pane.  Re-initializing should start the agent automatically.  If it's not starting, it may be a permissions issue.  You should be able to see the failure in the agents tab.

Comment: Yeah. I got error when I check generate a new snapshot and click OK

Comment: if you double click the snapshot agent, it should open a new window with details. what is the error?

Comment: There is no error in Log Reader Agent. The status is running.

Comment: What about the snapshot agent?

Comment: I only see the Log Reader Agent under Agents tab. I also restarted SQLSERVER AGENT

Comment: Are you selecting the publisher (server) or the publication within that server?

Comment: I double checked both. Werid..

Comment: Please follow this article to re-initialize from the publisher.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152466(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Re-initialize the subscription via Replication Monitor in SSMS, and generate a new snapshot during re-initialization.  This should clear up the missing record issues.

Comment: replication monitor could not start the snapshot agent to generate a new snapshot you must start the snapshot agent manually before subscription can be reinitialized. I got this error

Answer (score 2):

Dude, I [literally] just solved this a few minutes ago.  It pushed me about a fifty cent cab ride short of crazy.  The replicated database was part of a third party solution to offload their app's reporting.  As it turns out, one of their app servers was pointed to our reporting database rather than the live database.  Hence, "row not found at subscriber." because they were inserting and deleting records in the subscriber table.

Use `distribution.dbo.sp_helpsubscriptionerrors` to find the `xact_seqno`, then you can use `distribution.dbo.browsereplcmds` and this query

```
SELECT * 
   FROM distribution.dbo.MSarticles
   WHERE article_id in (
      SELECT article_id 
         FROM MSrepl_commands
         WHERE xact_seqno = 0x xact_seqno)
```

to get more info.  Use `distribution.dbo.sp_setsubscriptionxactseqno` if you want to get that single transaction "un-stuck" or just re-initialize.

I ended up running SQL Profiler on both the publisher and subscriber, then keyed off the tables I found with the queries above.  That's when I spotted the DML on the replicated table.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you all the pending commands for that article, which needs to be sent from distributor to subscriber.

Here you will get multiple records with same xact_seqno_start and xact_seqno_end but with different command ids.

You can check if all are delete commands, you can take primary key column value for all and insert them manually to subscriber server.

```
EXEC Sp_browsereplcmds
  @article_id = 813,
  @command_id = 1,
  @xact_seqno_start = '0x00099979000038D60001',
  @xact_seqno_end = '0x00099979000038D60001',
  @publisher_database_id = 1
```